# How to select checkboxes in Google Docs using Google Apps Script?

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, checkbox, google-docs, listitem

I'm new to Google Apps Script and I'm currently working on a project where I need to select all the checkboxes in a Google Doc using Google Apps Script, with the goal of determining if they've been checked or not, I will use this information to populate an external database. However, most of the solutions I've found are related to Google Sheets, not Google Docs.

I've tried using the `getListItems()` method to retrieve the list items in the document, hoping it would include the checkboxes as well. However, it seems to only select the bulleted points and not the checkboxes. When I run the code, I encounter the error `"TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toString')"` on the line where I try to access the `getGlyphType()`.

Here's the code snippet I've tried:

```
function getCheckboxValue() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const body = doc.getBody();

  const listItems = body.getListItems()
  
  for(let item of listItems){
    console.log(item.getGlyphType().toString())
  }
}
```

and this is what gets returned

```
4:47:46 PM  Notice  Execution started
4:47:46 PM  Info    BULLET
4:47:46 PM  Info    BULLET
4:47:46 PM  Info    BULLET
4:47:46 PM  Info    BULLET
4:47:46 PM  Info    BULLET
4:47:47 PM  Error   
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toString')
getCheckboxValue    @ Code.gs:8
```

I've also included an image of the document layout to provide a visual representation:
[Sample Doc with Bullets and Checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhyp1.png)

Is there a way to select all the checkboxes in a Google Docs document using Google Apps Script? If so, how can I modify my code to achieve this? Any guidance or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Thanks @Cooper it looks like that is only available to the `SpreadsheetsApp` object and not the `DocumentsApp` which is what I need for my usecase  unless I’ve totally missed something?

Comment: Hi. How many "checkboxes" in your live document?

Comment: @Tedinoz it changes on occasion but at current there are around 105 checkboxes, divided into separate sections.

Comment: I'm not sure what Cooper told you (there's no comment to reference), but it is correct that Google doesn't support (yet) identifying a glyph that matches a checklist. My bit of testing showed that exporting to PDF retained the glyph so possibly there is a PDF-> ??? conversion process to track the checkbox. Otherwise, I think inserting unicode characters would be the best (though not attractive) option.

Comment: Thanks @Tedinoz, Cooper was referencing a method on the SpreadsheetApp object which doesn’t exist in DocumentApp object so it’s possible to do what I want with sheets just not docs which is a bit frustrating. 

I’ll try the Unicode characters to see if that makes a difference. Thanks.